# Windows 7 Virtual machine .Net Webclient System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: .net, proxy, webclient, virtual-machine

What may cause 
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. Windows webclient
on Windows 7 virtual machine

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(Uri, "test.html"); // fails
        string html = client.DownloadString(Uri); // fails
```

I can't see any proxy settings in Internet Explorer and on the same box Com Automation driven from Visual Foxpro works without any proxy.

```
oxmlhttp = createobject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
oxmlhttp.open('GET', lcURL, .t.)
oxmlhttp.send()
```

Once rebooting box made it disappear , but right now after rebooting it persists.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how robust it is but adding these lines before invoking download solved my problem.

```
IWebProxy theProxy = client.Proxy;
if (theProxy != null)
{
    theProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}
```